# mvc javascript with DropDownList

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

So my view receives a model.
And I want to, in case the ID property of the model is -1, make the DDL select the default value "[Select]" that is in there.

DDL:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(cModel => cModel.QueueMonitorConfigTypeName, Enum.GetValues(typeof(BPM.Website.Models.PathType)).Cast<BPM.Website.Models.PathType>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = v.ToString(),
        Value = v.ToString()
    }), "[Select]", new { id = "ddlConfigTypeName" })
```

And the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var model = @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID
        if (model = -1)
        {
            $('#ddlConfigTypeName').select("[Select]")
        }
        else{}
    });
</script>
```

But for some reason , the intellisense of the js is telling me it is wrong.
The problem comes when I try to do a compare in the if.
I've tried with '=', '==', '===' and nothing works

It just keep saying syntax error. I guess it has some relation with adding the `@Model` tag but cant resolve it.
Any guesses?

Thanks

EDIT and if I change it with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if (@Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsIDel == -1)
        {
            $('#ddlConfigTypeName').select("[Select]")
        }
        else{}
    });
</script>
```

It still says the syntax error is in the `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It thinks you're doing an assignment (with just one = ) in this first one

```
$(function () {
    var model = @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID
    if (model = -1)
    {
        $('#ddlConfigTypeName').select("[Select]")
    }
    else{}
});
```

I replicated your situation, and this works:

```
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var model = @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID;
    if (model == -1){

        alert('got it');
    }
    else{

   alert(model);
  }
});
</script>
```

If this still doesn't work for you, can you check the value of the variable "model"? what is it returning?

Comment: Well, I tried with `=`, `==` and it says syntax error.
Seems like my intellisense says wrong things because it works.
Does your intellisense say `syntax error`?

Comment: Yes it does. Right on the last "});". But this is due to the use of "@Model". You can prove it by replacing "@Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID" with just a number, the error will go away. Anyway it won't affect your outcome.

Comment: Thank you :) so sad that intellisense doesnt read that properly because is confusing

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a ";" missing in the JS behind `var model = @Model.QueueMonitorConfigurationsID`
2. Change `if (model = -1)` to `if (model == -1)`

Comment: Ignore it, that's a bug in Intellisense. It runs.